# Why is my scrolling progress bar not starting on the left but in the middle? (React) (Image attached)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfTLJ.jpg)

The problem is that the scrolling progress bar doesn't go from the left to the right. Instead, it's in the middle and going both sides, which is ugly. How to fix this? I tried the same code on online code editors and it's normal there. Something is wrong with my VSCode?

Code:

```
import React from 'react';

class Progress extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            scrolled: 0,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollProgress);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrollProgress);
    }

    scrollProgress = () => {
        const scrollPx = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        const winHeightPx = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        const scrolled = `${(scrollPx / winHeightPx) * 100}%`;

        this.setState({
            scrolled: scrolled,
        });
    };

    render() {
        const progressContainerStyle = {
            background: 'transparent',
            height: '15px',
            position: 'fixed',
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            width: '100vw',
            zIndex: 100,
        };

        const progressBarStyle = {
            height: '15px',
            backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(-90deg, #6098df, #b581b0)',
            width: this.state.scrolled,
        };

        return (
            <div className="progress-container" style={progressContainerStyle}>
                <div className="progress-bar" style={progressBarStyle} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Progress;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `'margin: 0'` to both `progressContainerStyle` and `progressBarStyle` and now it miraculously works!